# OpenGL 4.0 FP64 capability

Tags: opengl, precision

recently I've been working on a project that requires FP64 support.

For now , I am checking if GPU supports `ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` extension. However, recently I tested this project on a laptop with Nvidia gt 540m, which does support OpenGL 4.0 , but it did not advertise said extension.

In OpenGL 4.0, `ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` became "core extension". What does that mean ? Does any gpu that supports opengl 4.0 support fp64 ? Does it have to advertise the extension, or is it implicit that it supports this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it means is what it says. ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 is what is formally called a "backwards compatibility extension". This means that it is identical to the 4.0 functionality, to the point where the enumerators and functions don't even have an `ARB` suffix. This means that it is always valid to use these enums/functions if the extension is present *or* if the version number is >= to the OpenGL version where it was adopted.

The purpose of this is to allow hardware to expose this functionality which can't implement the rest of 4.0. And users can use either kind of hardware without requiring any code changes (even the enum/function names) to user code. They simply need to check the version and the extension, and use the feature if either is present.

Odds are good that the extension is only missing due to a driver bug. I say that because 3 [separate reports](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gl_generatereport.php?reportID=165) [for your](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gl_generatereport.php?reportID=356) [exact hardware](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gl_generatereport.php?reportID=878) all explicitly list that extension as being supported for your hardware. So if your drivers are up-to-date, it may just be a recent driver bug. If they're older, updating may fix it.

Alternatively, the code that checks for the presence of this extension may be buggy.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer that I was looking for, Now only to get shaders compiling with `#VERSION 400` and `#VERSION 330 + extension`.